# jQuery formBuilder with SQL lookup based on inputs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am writing a form where I require a SQL lookup based on the input of a field. I am using jQuery and [formBuilder](https://formbuilder.online/).

The field will be for a ID number, then I wish to have a statement afterwards along the lines of: `Your name is $name, is that correct?`

The query would be something like:

```
SELECT firstname from maindb.users WHERE id='$id';
```

I'm a complete beginner at jQuery so this is all new, I only have beginner/intermediate PHP knowledge so far. I understand that Ajax is the best option here, I wonder if someone could possibly share a code example to achieve this?

The next question I wonder if I could ask some input on. I would like to make use of the formBuilder autocomplete text fields. Can I populate a list of autocomplete options for this field using a database lookup? The form option code syntax is:

```
<ul id="reg-list" class="fb-autocomplete-list">
    <li value="option-1">Option 1</li>
    <li value="option-2">Option 2</li>
</ul>
```

And the query to populate it would be something like:

```
SELECT reg FROM maindb.vehicles;
```

Hopefully this all makes sense.

Comment: Please ask only one question with your question.

Comment: yeah, Hopefully